# How do I backup Titanium Backup?

Tags: titanium-backup

I want to install Titanium Backup on a new phone and would like to carry over the settings from my old phone, which include current backup schedules. How can I go about this in order to avoid having to recreate them manually?

I've checked the current backups and it looks like TB does not do backups of itself. I also have "My Backup Pro" installed, but it doesn't list TB as a selectable item for backup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the Titanium Backup settings page and enable (it it isn't already enabled) the `Auto Sync TB Settings` option. Then you should be able restore the file created on your SD Card to your new phone.

Comment: The file is created in `sdcard\data\com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup\settings\ `, so copying the folder to the new phone transferred the settings perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it! :-)

Comment: If the option wasn't enabled, you'll need to run a backup for the settings folder to be created.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Helium to backup the full app. You can choose to backup to Google Drive or to your storage. If storage is chosen, it will backup the app to Carbon folder. Remember to uncheck "Smaller app backup" to backup the full app. You can then copy the backup from the folder to your new phone and restore it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the open source [OAndBackupX](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.machiav3lli.backup/) and it worked fine :)